# How to evaluate $\frac{1}{\sinh^4(x\pm i\epsilon)}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I should evaluate the following expression for $\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+$:
$$\frac{1}{\sinh^4(x\pm i\epsilon)}$$
I know that $\frac{1}{x\pm i\epsilon}=P\frac{1}{x}\mp\delta(x)$, so I tried to obtain something similiar. I started by exploiting the identity $\sinh(a+b)=\sinh(a)\cosh(b)+\cosh(a)\sinh(b)$ and then I expanded in Taylor series around $\epsilon=0$, keeping (after evaluating the power) only the first two terms. In this way I get, after a "rationalitazion":
$$\frac{1}{4\cosh(x)\sinh^3(x)}\frac{\frac{1}{4}\tanh(x)\mp i\epsilon}{\frac{1}{16}\tanh^2(x)+\epsilon^2}$$
After this point, however, I do not know how to continue. Honestly I am not even sure that neglecting the $O(\epsilon^2)$-terms is correct, since $\sinh(x)$ could be equal to zero.

Comment: Isn't it $\frac{1}{\sinh^4(x)}$?

Comment: @Gary do you mean the final result? There should be also a derivate of a Dirac's delta

Comment: Are you missing an integral in your question?

Comment: Nope. Unless you don't want to evaluate it by evaluating its action on another, generic, function, like $\int\frac{1}{\mathrm{sinh}^4(x\pm i\epsilon)}f(x)$ @Gary

Comment: For $\operatorname {csch}^4(x + i \epsilon) - (x + i \epsilon)^{-4} + (2/3) (x + i \epsilon)^{-2}$, the distributional limit and the pointwise limit are the same, so the structure of the result is a regular distribution plus $(x + i0)^{-n}$ terms. If we want to use $x^{-n}$ instead of $(x + i0)^{-n}$, with $x^{-n}$ defined as $(-1)^{n - 1}/(n - 1)!$ times the distributional derivative of order $n - 1$ of $\mathcal P(1/x)$, we have
$$(x + i0)^{-n} =
x^{-n} - \pi i \frac {(-1)^{n - 1}} {(n - 1)!} \delta^{(n - 1)}(x).$$

Comment: @Maxim Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If you start with
$$\sinh (x+i \epsilon )=\sinh (x)+i \epsilon  \cosh (x)-\frac{1}{2} \epsilon ^2 \sinh
   (x)-\frac{1}{6} i \epsilon ^3 \cosh (x)+O\left(\epsilon ^4\right)$$ Using multiple angle formulae
$$\sinh^4 (x+i \epsilon )=\sinh ^4(x)+4 i \epsilon  \sinh ^3(x) \cosh (x)+\epsilon ^2 (\cosh (2
   x)-\cosh (4 x))+\frac{2}{3} i \epsilon ^3 (\sinh (2 x)-2 \sinh (4
   x))+O\left(\epsilon ^4\right)$$ Now long division
$$\frac 1 {\sinh^4 (x+i \epsilon)}=\text{csch}^4(x)-4 i \epsilon  \coth (x) \text{csch}^4(x)-2 \epsilon ^2
   \left((2 \cosh (2 x)+3) \text{csch}^6(x)\right)+\frac{4}{3} i \epsilon
   ^3 (13 \cosh (x)+2 \cosh (3 x)) \text{csch}^7(x)+O\left(\epsilon
   ^4\right)$$  that is to say
$$\text{csch}^4(x)\Big[1-4 i \epsilon  \coth (x)-2 \epsilon ^2 \left((2 \cosh (2 x)+3)
   \text{csch}^2(x)\right)+O\left(\epsilon ^3\right) \Big]$$

If you try for $x=1$ and  $\epsilon=0.01$ the above truncated series gives $(0.523466\, -0.0275352 i)$ while the exact value is $(0.523467\, -0.0275178 i)$.

**Edit**

If you consider the  series expansion of $\text{csch}^4(x+\delta )$ around $\delta=0$ you could transform it into the simplest Padé approximant and obtain
$$\text{csch}^4(x+\delta )=\text{csch}^4(x)\,\,\frac {\sinh (2 x)-\delta  \,(2 \cosh (2 x)+1) }{\sinh (2 x)+\delta\,  (2 \cosh (2 x)+3) }$$ Just make $\delta=\pm i\epsilon$ got get the result.

For the worked example, this gives $(0.523467\, -0.027512 i)$